# Resharper 5.0 - initial impressions

Tags: visual-studio, resharper-5.0

Now that VS 2010 is officially released, I'm thinking of upgrading to Resharper 5.0 and I just wondered if any of you could provide any feedback on your impressions so far.

Some specific questions:

1. I like Resharper a lot, but it's pretty slow if you have a slow disk (one of my machines has a 5400RPM drive and it does not run very optimally on that machine.).  I just wondered if you had noticed any speed improvements in 5.0.
2. Is Resharper 5.0 required for VS 2010, or will Resharper 4.5.1 still work? I couldn't find anything definitive on the JetBrains website, but I may have just missed it. The impression I get is 5.0 is required for VS 2010.
3. Any other feedback you have on Resharper 5.0 and what you like/dislike about it is much appreciated.  I'm not sure when I'm going to be officially moving to VS 2010, but I guess I could go ahead and get Resharper 5.0 even if I stay on VS 2008 for a while. Are there any new features in 5.0 that you've found that are really nice which aren't in the 4.5.1 version (I checked out the [features](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/) page, but nothing really jumps out except for the native nunit support which looks nice).?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all Resharper 5.0 supports VS 2010. The older versions won't support VS 2010. Since I have been using Resharper 5.0 for a few days I can say that it is as good as the older version. For enhancements you can check this page : http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html?R5blog

Answer (score 2):

R# 5.0 RTM is horribly slow with VS2010 RTM.  I've actually just disabled it.

I'm having all sorts of UI lag issues.  I have a Win7 X64 box, quad core 2.4GHz with 8Gb and Quadro graphics card and SSD disks and it's still almost unusable.

Comment: I've just worked out this appears to be related to over-use of the #region directive.  If you remove #region, it is slightly faster.

When it's the speed of vim/textpad I'll be happy. The problems it solves are not hard!

Answer (score 0):

Browsing .Net Framework source code with just a single F12 click is quite impressive.

Comment: Que?, thats "go to definition" in regular Visual Studio? Does Resharper do a better job for c++ code here?

Comment: Yes, that's "go to definition". In c# project it shows .Net Framework class source code too.

Answer (score 0):

Performance has been comparable with Resharper 4.5. There are a couple of very nice new features - `Inspect > Code Issues in Solution` in particular is great. See http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html?R5blog as mentioned by Semih.